# Iterate through a json feed in python

Tags: python, json

I'm iterating through such a feed:

```
{"siri":{"serviceDelivery":{"responseTimestamp":"2017-03-14T18:37:23Z","producerRef":"IVTR_RELAIS","status":"true","estimatedTimetableDelivery":[
{"lineRef":{"value":"C01742"},"directionRef":{"value":""},"datedVehicleJourneyRef":{"value":"SNCF-ACCES:VehicleJourney::UPAL97_20170314:LOC"},"vehicleMode":["RAIL"],"routeRef":{},"publishedLineName":[{"value":"RER A"}],"directionName":[],"originRef":{},"originName":[],"originShortName":[],"destinationDisplayAtOrigin":[],"via":[],"destinationRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:40918:"},"destinationName":[{"value":"GARE DE CERGY LE HAUT"}],"destinationShortName":[],"originDisplayAtDestination":[],"operatorRef":{"value":"SNCF-ACCES:Operator::SNCF:"},"productCategoryRef":{},"vehicleJourneyName":[],"journeyNote":[],"firstOrLastJourney":"UNSPECIFIED","additionalVehicleJourneyRef":[],"estimatedCalls":{"estimatedCall":[{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:411321:"},"expectedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T20:02:00.000Z","expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T20:02:00.000Z","aimedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T20:02:00.000Z","aimedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T20:02:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:411368:"},"expectedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T20:09:00.000Z","expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T20:09:00.000Z","aimedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T20:09:00.000Z","aimedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T20:09:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:411352:"},"expectedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T20:05:00.000Z","expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T20:05:00.000Z","aimedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T20:05:00.000Z","aimedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T20:05:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:41528:"},"expectedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T19:56:00.000Z","expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T19:56:00.000Z","aimedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T19:56:00.000Z","aimedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T19:56:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:40918:"},"expectedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T20:12:00.000Z","aimedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T20:12:00.000Z","aimedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T20:12:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]}]},"recordedAtTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:12.314Z"}
,{"lineRef":{"value":"C00049"},"directionRef":{"value":""},"datedVehicleJourneyRef":{"value":"004_DEVILLAIRS:VehicleJourney::109173051020957:LOC"},"vehicleMode":[],"routeRef":{},"publishedLineName":[{"value":"42"}],"directionName":[{"value":"Aller"}],"originRef":{},"originName":[],"originShortName":[],"destinationDisplayAtOrigin":[],"via":[],"destinationRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:BP:12689:"},"destinationName":[{"value":"L'Onde Maison des Arts"}],"destinationShortName":[],"originDisplayAtDestination":[],"operatorRef":{"value":"004_DEVILLAIRS:Operator::004_DEVILLAIRS_Operator__004_DEVILLAIRS_Company__Devillairs 4_LOC_:"},"productCategoryRef":{},"vehicleJourneyName":[],"journeyNote":[],"firstOrLastJourney":"UNSPECIFIED","additionalVehicleJourneyRef":[],"estimatedCalls":{"estimatedCall":[{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:12690:"},"expectedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:44:26.000Z","expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:44:26.000Z","aimedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:43:39.000Z","aimedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:43:39.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:12684:"},"expectedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:38:51.000Z","expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:38:51.000Z","aimedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:34:51.000Z","aimedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:34:51.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:40538:"},"expectedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:40:53.000Z","expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:40:53.000Z","aimedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:24.000Z","aimedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:24.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:12678:"},"expectedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:41:10.000Z","expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:41:10.000Z","aimedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:57.000Z","aimedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:57.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:12682:"},"expectedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:40:00.000Z","expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:40:00.000Z","aimedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:36:21.000Z","aimedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:36:21.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:41690:"},"expectedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:42:17.000Z","expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:42:17.000Z","aimedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:39:00.000Z","aimedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:39:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:12743:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:15:00.000Z","aimedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:15:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:12680:"},"expectedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:40:24.000Z","expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:40:24.000Z","aimedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:36:52.000Z","aimedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:36:52.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:12676:"},"expectedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:41:42.000Z","expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:41:42.000Z","aimedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:38:29.000Z","aimedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:38:29.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]}]},"recordedAtTime":"2017-03-14T18:35:51.000Z"}
,{"lineRef":{"value":"C01375"},"directionRef":{"value":""},"datedVehicleJourneyRef":{"value":"RATP:VehicleJourney::M5.R.1937.1:LOC"},"vehicleMode":[],"routeRef":{},"publishedLineName":[{"value":"Place d'Italie / Bobigny Pablo Picasso"}],"directionName":[{"value":"Bobigny Pablo Picasso"}],"originRef":{},"originName":[],"originShortName":[],"destinationDisplayAtOrigin":[],"via":[],"destinationRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:22015:"},"destinationName":[{"value":"Bobigny Pablo Picasso"}],"destinationShortName":[],"originDisplayAtDestination":[],"operatorRef":{},"productCategoryRef":{},"vehicleJourneyName":[],"journeyNote":[],"firstOrLastJourney":"UNSPECIFIED","additionalVehicleJourneyRef":[],"estimatedCalls":{"estimatedCall":[{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:22003:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:22008:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:22017:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:21952:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:22009:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:22016:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:22007:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:21903:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:22005:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:22006:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:22004:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:22012:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:22011:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:22013:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:21981:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:22000:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:22010:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:22002:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:22001:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:37:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]}]},"recordedAtTime":"2017-03-14T18:36:55.890Z"}
,{"lineRef":{"value":"C00774"},"directionRef":{"value":""},"datedVehicleJourneyRef":{"value":"STIVO:VehicleJourney::268437511:LOC"},"vehicleMode":[],"routeRef":{},"publishedLineName":[{"value":"CERGY PREFECTURE-VAUREAL TOUPETS"}],"directionName":[{"value":"R"}],"originRef":{},"originName":[],"originShortName":[],"destinationDisplayAtOrigin":[],"via":[],"destinationRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:10118:"},"destinationName":[{"value":"Préfecture RER"}],"destinationShortName":[],"originDisplayAtDestination":[],"operatorRef":{},"productCategoryRef":{},"vehicleJourneyName":[],"journeyNote":[],"firstOrLastJourney":"UNSPECIFIED","additionalVehicleJourneyRef":[],"estimatedCalls":{"estimatedCall":[{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:8729:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:39:31.000Z","aimedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:39:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:8731:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:40:31.000Z","aimedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:40:20.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:8730:"},"expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:40:46.000Z","aimedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:39:51.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]}]},"recordedAtTime":"2017-03-14T18:36:43.000Z"}
,{"lineRef":{"value":"C00697"},"directionRef":{"value":""},"datedVehicleJourneyRef":{"value":"SRVSAE:VehicleJourney::34661-1:LOC"},"vehicleMode":["BUS"],"routeRef":{},"publishedLineName":[{"value":"H   "}],"directionName":[],"originRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:BP:20399:"},"originName":[{"value":"Versailles Rive Gauche"}],"originShortName":[],"destinationDisplayAtOrigin":[],"via":[],"destinationRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:BP:4122:"},"destinationName":[{"value":"La Celle St Cloud - Gare"}],"destinationShortName":[],"originDisplayAtDestination":[],"operatorRef":{"value":"SRVSAE:Operator::56 :"},"productCategoryRef":{},"vehicleJourneyName":[{"value":"34661-1"}],"journeyNote":[],"firstOrLastJourney":"OTHER_SERVICE","additionalVehicleJourneyRef":[],"estimatedCalls":{"estimatedCall":[{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:4062:"},"expectedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:39:55.000Z","expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:39:55.000Z","aimedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:35:00.000Z","aimedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:35:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:4064:"},"expectedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:38:58.000Z","expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:38:58.000Z","aimedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:34:10.000Z","aimedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:34:10.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"STIF:StopPoint:Q:4068:"},"expectedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:36:48.000Z","expectedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:36:48.000Z","aimedArrivalTime":"2017-03-14T18:32:00.000Z","aimedDepartureTime":"2017-03-14T18:32:00.000Z","stopPointName":[],"originDisplay":[],"destinationDisplay":[],"arrivalOperatorRefs":[]}]},"recordedAtTime":"2017-03-14T18:33:37.000Z"}
]}}}
```

Using a python script:

```
import datetime
import time

import dateutil.parser
import pytz
import json
import gtfs_realtime_pb2
from traceback import print_exc

EPOCH = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)

def handle_siri(raw):
    siri_data = json.loads(raw.decode('utf-8'))['siri']
    msg = gtfs_realtime_pb2.FeedMessage()
    msg.header.gtfs_realtime_version = "1.0"
    msg.header.incrementality = msg.header.FULL_DATASET
    msg.header.timestamp = int(time.time())
#    msg.header.timestamp = long(siri_data['serviceDelivery']['responseTimestamp'])

    for i, vehicle in enumerate(siri_data['serviceDelivery']['estimatedTimetableDelivery']):
        route_id = vehicle['lineRef']['value'][:6].strip()

        if len(vehicle['datedVehicleJourneyRef']) > 0:
            operator = vehicle['datedVehicleJourneyRef'].split('[:.]')
            if operator[0] == "RATP":
                sens = operator[4]
                if operator[4] == "A":
                    ent.trip_update.trip.direction_id = 0
                if operator[4] == "R":
                    ent.trip_update.trip.direction_id = 1

            if operator[0] != "RATP":
                continue
#        direction = vehicle['monitoredVehicleJourney']['directionRef'] # Il faudra editer le code pour le definir pour les autres...
#        ent.trip_update.trip.direction_id = int(direction) - 1 # Il faudra editer le code pour le definir pour les autres...

        if 'estimatedCalls' not in vehicle['monitoredVehicleJourney']:
            continue

        for call in vehicle['monitoredVehicleJourney']['estimatedCalls']:
            stoptime = ent.trip_update.stop_time_update.add()
            if 'stopPointRef' in vehicle['monitoredVehicleJourney']['estimatedCall']:
                stoptime.stop_id = vehicle['monitoredVehicleJourney']['estimatedCall']['stopPointRef']
            arrival_time = (dateutil.parser.parse(call['expectedArrivalTime']) - EPOCH).total_seconds()
            stoptime.arrival.time = int(arrival_time)
            departure_time = (dateutil.parser.parse(call['expectedDepartureTime']) - EPOCH).total_seconds()
            stoptime.departure.time = int(departure_time)

        ent = msg.entity.add() # On garde ca ?
        ent.id = str(i) #
        ent.trip_update.timestamp = vehicle['recordedAtTime'] #
        ent.trip_update.trip.route_id = route_id #

#        try:
#            int(vehicle['MonitoredVehicleJourney']['Delay'])
#        except:
#            print_exc()
#            print vehicle, vehicle['MonitoredVehicleJourney']['Delay']

#            continue

#        ent.trip_update.trip.start_date = vehicle['MonitoredVehicleJourney']['FramedVehicleJourneyRef']['DataFrameRef']['value'].replace("-", "")
#        if 'datedVehicleJourneyRef' in vehicle['monitoredVehicleJourney']['framedVehicleJourneyRef']: # doesn't exist in our feed
#            start_time = vehicle['monitoredVehicleJourney']['framedVehicleJourneyRef']['datedVehicleJourneyRef']
#            ent.trip_update.trip.start_time = start_time[:2]+":"+start_time[2:]+":00"
#
#
#        if 'vehicleRef' in vehicle['monitoredVehicleJourney']: # doesn't exist in our feed
#            ent.trip_update.vehicle.label = vehicle['monitoredVehicleJourney']['vehicleRef']['value']

    return msg
```

Unfortunately,

This loop is not working, returning an error, while it should iterate through each item starting with `{"lineRef"`:

```
File "/home/nicolas/packaging/stif.py", line 24, in handle_siri operator = vehicle['datedVehicleJourneyRef'].split('[:.]') AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Could you please help me fix this?

Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: I think that you should use more variables and item.get('field') sentences to be sure that you are getting the contents you are expecting.

Comment: please share the error message as well.

Comment: it works if I loop through dictionary, so there might be problem with loading json, please share the error message as @Vikash Singh suggested

Comment: I got the following error: `File "/home/nicolas/packaging/stif.py", line 24, in handle_siri
    operator = vehicle['datedVehicleJourneyRef'].split('[:.]')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: I also only pasted a part of the SIRI-lite json feed, as it is way more bigger than that (that's the reason why I need efficient iterations)

Comment: the error says you cannot split `dict` which is correct. I don't know what you actually need to extract, because I cannot see `[:.]` in data, but try `vehicle['datedVehicleJourneyRef']['value'].split('::')` for the beginning.

Comment: I need to split using both : and . as a separator, to divide for example this value: `RATP:VehicleJourney::M5.R.1937.1:LOC` into "RATP", "VehicleJourney", "", "M5", "R", "1937", "1", "LOC".

Answer (score 0):

JSON files are tricky.  I did something similar with Scratch files.
https://gist.github.com/doyousketch2/8c1d07923554c78ed888b089e45536e2
This will get you your keys and entries.
If you need more help figuring out how to parse those, just reply.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
##=========================================================
##  SiriJsonExtract.py  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  17 Mar, 2017
##
##  Eli Innis
##  Twitter:  @ Doyousketch2
##  Email:  Doyousketch2 @ yahoo.com
##  GNU GPLv3  gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
##=========================================================
##  libs  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

import json               ##  convert .json file into dicts

##=========================================================
##  vars  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

defaultDir  = '/home/eli/Programming/Python/siri/'
siri  = 'siri.json'
msg = []

##=========================================================
##  open file  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

with open((defaultDir + siri), 'r') as data:               ##  "with" is Python's crash resistant file open
    jay = json .load(data)                                 ##  load JSON file into the variable jay

##==============================================
##  In order to use a JSON file, we need to traverse down it's branches.
##  I modified code that was intended for recursive printing:
##  code.activestate.com/recipes/578094-recursively-print-nested-dictionaries

##  'item' is the item we are currently scanning
##  'depth' is how far we are within it, ie  this[0] [1] [2] [3]
##  'key' is used for dictionaries, so we can get the correct values associated with that particular key

def scan(item, depth = 0, key = ''):
    global msg
    tabs = lambda n: ' ' * n                               ##  simple spaces will suffice for tabs

    if isinstance(item, dict):                             ##  if we have a dictionary entry
        for key, value in sorted(item .items()):           ##  iterate through keys & values
            msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'key:   %s' % key)
            scan(value, depth + 2, key)                    ##  scan deeper

    elif isinstance(item, list):                           ##  if we have a list entry
        for listitem in item:                              ##  iterate through list items
            scan(listitem, depth + 2)                      ##  go even deeper in this list

    else:                                                  ##  can't go down. number, boolean, or empty set
        msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'item:   %s\n' % item)   ##  append the command or arg,  with a bit of padding,
                                                           ##  so the next one we paste doesn't collide.
    return msg

##==============================================
##  main  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

scan(jay)  ##  begin our scan here

text = '\n' .join(msg)
print(text)

##==============================================
##  eof  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Yes, I would need some help to parse this, please... I need to retrieve the exact variable names my current script is trying to get, when it is invoked by this one: https://aurora.acolytesanonymes.org/s/qPmtwcz0vqisS3I the feed data I need to read is from a web URL, not a file.

Comment: OK, I'll look into it.  They didn't make it easy, because they return keys with the name 'value'

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to see how it's iterating through the JSON entries in first answer.
It gets more complicated here.  Half of it is in French.
My dad speaks French, but I've only ever heard bits and pieces.

It would help if I could see what the desired output would look like.
I don't know what RATP is.  This seems to be a bus schedule?
I don't get why everything is converted into seconds.

Can you write up a rough-draft of how you want the output to look?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
##=========================================================
##  SiriJsonExtract.py  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  17 Mar, 2017
##
##  Eli Innis
##  Twitter:  @ Doyousketch2
##  Email:  Doyousketch2 @ yahoo.com
##
##  GNU GPLv3  gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
##
##=========================================================
##  libs  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

import datetime
import time
import pytz
import json
from dateutil.parser import parse

##=========================================================
##  vars  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

defaultDir  = '/home/eli/Programming/Python/siri/'
siri  = 'siri.json'

##=========================================================
##  global placeholder

msg = []

##=========================================================
##  open file  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

with open((defaultDir + siri), 'r') as data:               ##  "with" is Python's crash resistant file open
    jay = json .load(data)                                 ##  load JSON file into the variable jay

##=========================================================
##  scan funct  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

def scan(item, depth = 0, key = ''):
    global msg
    EPOCH = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
    # stoptime = ent.trip_update.stop_time_update.add()
    tabs = lambda n: ' ' * n                               ##  simple spaces will suffice for tabs

    if isinstance(item, dict):                             ##  if we have a dictionary entry
        for key, value in sorted(item .items()):           ##  iterate through keys & values
            if key .endswith('ArrivalTime') :
                msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'Arrival:   %s  Time: %s' % (key, parse(value)))
                arrival_time = (parse(value) - EPOCH).total_seconds()
                # stoptime.arrival.time = int(arrival_time)

            elif key .endswith('DepartureTime') :
                msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'Departure:   %s  Time: %s' % (key, parse(value)))
                departure_time = (parse(value) - EPOCH).total_seconds()
                # stoptime.departure.time = int(departure_time)

            elif key == 'recordedAtTime':
                msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'recordedAtTime:   %s' % parse(value))

            elif key .startswith('datedVehicle'):
                msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'Operator:   %s' % value['value'])

            elif key == 'originName':
                if len(value) > 0:
                    msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'originName:   %s' % value[0]['value'])

            elif key == 'originRef':
                if len(value) > 0:
                    msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'originRef:   %s' % value['value'])

            elif key == 'directionName':
                if len(value) > 0:
                    msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'directionName:   %s' % value[0]['value'])

            elif key == 'publishedLineName':
                msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'publishedLineName:   %s' % value[0]['value'])

            elif key == 'destinationName':
                msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'destinationName:   %s' % value[0]['value'])

            elif key == 'destinationRef':
                msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'destinationRef:   %s' % value['value'])

            elif key == 'operatorRef':
                if len(value) > 0:
                    msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'operatorRef:   %s' % value['value'])

            elif key == 'vehicleMode':
                if len(value) > 0:
                    msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'vehicleMode:   %s' % value[0])

            elif key == 'lineRef':
                msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'lineRef:   %s' % value['value'])

            elif key == 'vehicleJourneyName':
                if len(value) > 0:
                    msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'vehicleJourneyName:   %s' % value[0]['value'])

            elif key == 'firstOrLastJourney':
                if len(value) > 0:
                    msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'firstOrLastJourney:   %s' % value)

            elif key == 'stopPointRef':
                if len(value) > 0:
                    msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'stopPointRef:   %s' % value['value'])

            elif key == 'producerRef':
                if len(value) > 0:
                    msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'producerRef:   %s' % value)

            elif key .endswith('Timestamp'):
                msg .append(tabs(depth) + '%s:   %s' % (key, parse(value)))

            elif key == 'status':
                if len(value) > 0:
                    msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'status:   %c' % value[0])

            elif key == 'value':
                msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'Value:   %s' % value)

            else:
                msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'key:   %s' % key)
                scan(value, depth + 2, key)                ##  scan deeper

    elif isinstance(item, list):                           ##  if we have a list entry
        for listitem in item:                              ##  iterate through list items
            scan(listitem, depth + 2)                      ##  go even deeper in this list

    else:                                                  ##  can't go down. number, boolean, or empty set
        msg .append(tabs(depth) + 'item:   %s\n' % item)   ##  append the command or arg,  with a bit of padding,
                                                           ##  so the next one we paste doesn't collide.
    return msg

##=========================================================
##  main    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

scan(jay)  ##  begin our scan here

text = '\n' .join(msg)
print(text)

##=========================================================
##  eof  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```