# Convert a raw tweet string to a JSON object in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm using twitter's API to download raw tweets so I can play with them. The iterator loop they gave in the example looks something like this (I added an if condition to run the loop n times, not shown here):

```
iterator = twitter_stream.statuses.sample()
for tweet in iterator:
   print (json.dumps(tweet))
   break
```

These commands output the entire JSON object in the correct format.

To extract the "text" item from the raw tweet json object, I tried using the .get("text") operator on the

```
txts = []
for tweet in iterator:
   txts.append((json.dumps(tweet)).get("text"))
   break
print (txts)
```

But I get an error saying "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'"

So I searched around and found a solution where they wrote all the outputs from json.dumps(tweet) to a file, use json.loads(jsonfile) to a variable, and tried to use the .get("text") operator on it to load the text:

```
fl = open("ipjson.json", "a")
for tweet in iterator:
   fl.write(json.dumps(tweet))
   break
fl.flush()
decode = json.loads(fl)

for item in decode:
   txt = item.get("text")
   txts.append(txt)
print (txts)
```

But this gives me another error saying "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'TextIOWrapper'"

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better/easier way to extract text from a raw tweet JSON object?

Comment: Could you provide output of `print(json.dumps(tweet))` and point what exact data you want to get from there?

Comment: You should not need to do a dump and then load. The info is likely already in the tweet variable.

Answer (score 2):

For the first example you don't need JSON you can just do:

```
txts = []
for status in statuses:
  txts.append(status.text)
```

For the second example you're handling the JSON incorrectly. You should instead do:

```
txts = []
for status in statuses:
  txts.append(json.dumps(status))

with open('ipjson.json','w') as fou:
  json.dump(txts,fou)
```

And to read it back in:

```
with open('ipjson.json','r') as fin:
  txts = json.load(fin)

for txt in txts:
  print(json.loads(txt)['text'])
```

Please note that when you're writing and reading the JSON you use *dump* and *load* but with the individual JSON objects you're using *dumps* and *loads*.

Answer (score 0):

JSON files require recursive scanning,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42855667/3342050
or known locations within the structure.

After you get your dict, list, & entries, you parse through for specific values:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42860573/3342050
This is entirely dependent upon what data is returned,
because keys will be unique to that structure.